# How many schedules can be handled by rufus scheduler?

Tags: performance, jruby, rufus-scheduler

I'm building a IFTTT like platform here.

In short, rufus scheduler is great. and I know it uses thread pool(28 threads by default? => 3.x.x)

My platform is expected to handle more than 1000 schedules maybe more than that.

on Jruby, as Singleton. Is there a performance problem with this expectation? should I increase max thread pool size? then how many threads should I increase? Is there a guide for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completed benchmark, code is as below.. My system has a job queue in it, so rufus-scheduler's handler is going to do very short and light tasks only. For example queueing jobs. In code, Just logging interval between **job.last_time** and **time**.
I assumed the bigger the interval, the lower performance. like **"delayed"**

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
require 'awesome_print'
require 'logger'

SCHEDULE_COUNT = 1000
MAX_THREAD = 224
schedule_samples = { type: "cron", schedule: "* * * * *"}

$logger = Logger.new("benchmark.log")
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.singleton(:max_work_threads => MAX_THREAD)

class Handler
  def self.call(job, time)
    $logger.info job.last_time - time
  end
end

SCHEDULE_COUNT.times do
  scheduler.send( schedule_samples[:type].to_sym, schedule_samples[:schedule], Handler)
end

sleep 600
```

The result is a little bit disappointed.. the more threads, the better. But I got the approximate delay for my future system, and it's reasonably acceptable.

I ran this code at my laptop, 1 core 1GB RHEL 64bit Vmware and 4 core 4GB RHEL 64bit Vmware.

Jruby version

- labtop jruby 1.7.16.1 (1.9.3p392)
- Linux jruby 1.7.19 (1.9.3p551)

These are not exactly same, but it should be okay..?
The link chart is average of all intervals. 
[Benchmark Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vN3Iz.png)

---

I can keep increase max threads to find out the performance peak. But I decide won't do it. I gonna use better machine for production environment. 1000 ~ 2000ms delay shouldn't be a problem. (in benchmark largest delay was 700ms at 1 Core)

## Again, Rufus-Scheduler is great!!

Comment: Very cool, thanks ! Although I think that JRuby deserves all the credit. Rufus-scheduler is very dumb.

Answer (score 0):

Rufus-scheduler queues its schedules in the order "next to trigger first". So your list could get long, but rufus doesn't loop through the whole list each time (and each time means every 0.3s approx (default frequency)), it stops iterating as soon as the next element is "in the future". So a long list should be OK.

Reading the question, I have the impression you're more concerned about lots of schedules triggering at once and/or overlapping. IIRC, JRuby uses Java threads and those are said to be multicore friendly, so good hardware could help.

Why don't you build a prototype? You bomb it with schedules and observe, learn, tune (and potentially discard rufus-scheduler if not good enough). Build your benchmark, then answers to your question will come to you.

Comment: I'll do as you said. I hope I can share the benchmark result.. Working on it!!